# memory deallocation doubly linked list C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind

I have created my own implementation of a doubly linked list for learning purposes. I am doing some testing to make sure the memory is being deallocated correctly. In `main.cpp`, I have the following:

```
list<int> pointer;
int *x = new int(1);
int *y = new int(2);
int *z = new int(3);
pointer.insertBack(*x);
pointer.insertBack(*y);
pointer.insertBack(*z);
pointer.printForward();
pointer.printReverse();
```

Obviously memory is being allocated because of the call to `new`. Do I have to call delete myself after all of that code or should the destructor for the list handle the memory deallocation? If I use an `int` instead of pointers, no memory leaks are found. I am using valgrind to check for memory leaks.

Comment: Doesn't valgrind tell you?

Comment: The list never sees your pointers, because you are still passing integers (e.g. insertBack(*x)) to insertBack() rather than pointers (e.g. insertBack(x), which wouldn't compile anyway unless you were using a list<int *> rather than a list<int>).  So the list object will definitely not delete the memory you allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store a pointer to data in your list, you have to delete that data yourself, the list wont (or shouldn't) do it for you.
best way to do it is to get the data, use it, then delete it in the same function.

Also depending on your implementation of the linked list you may have to delete the memory being used by each node in the list internally.

If you are talking about deleting the list, if you don't need the data you should delete it before deleting the list.